# How to display a progress bar on a Mac Cocoa App (Swift)

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, progress-bar, iboutlet

I am currently learning Swift and particularly for Mac, and I tried to make sort of a Pokemon battle game. For this, I wanted to display progress bars for the health points, but all I can found are the striped one. I don't know if I can make them change regarding a given value, or if I am not using the right kind of IBOutlet.

**If anyone knows how to display progress bars, that is all what I need** :)

Thank you

(I am french so excuse my possible mistakes...)

Edit: Here is some of my code

Variables:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

@IBOutlet var window: NSWindow?

var firstPokemon:Pokemon = Pokemon(name: "Aquali", level: 50, HP: 245, power: 10)
//[...]
@IBOutlet var firstPokemonHealthBar: NSProgressIndicator!
//[...]
var firstPokemonOriginalHP:Float = 0

var secondPokemon:Pokemon = Pokemon(name: "Pikachu", level: 90, HP: 300, power: 13)
//[...]
@IBOutlet var secondPokemonHealthBar: NSProgressIndicator!
//[...]
var secondPokemonOriginalHP:Float = 0
```

initialize:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?)
{

    firstPokemonOriginalHP = firstPokemon.HP
    secondPokemonOriginalHP = secondPokemon.HP
}
```

update (called after each attack)

```
func update(str:String)
{
    if firstPokemon.HP < 0 {firstPokemon.HP = 0}
    if secondPokemon.HP < 0 {secondPokemon.HP = 0}


    //firstPokemonName.stringValue = firstPokemon.name
    //firstPokemonLevel.stringValue = "Level: " + String(Int(firstPokemon.level))
    //firstPokemonHP.stringValue = "\(Int(firstPokemon.HP))/\(Int(firstPokemonOriginalHP))hp"
    firstPokemonHealthBar.doubleValue = Double(firstPokemon.HP/firstPokemonOriginalHP)
    //firstPokemonPicture.image = NSImage(named: "\(firstPokemon.name)")
    //firstPokemonPicture.image.size = firstPokemonPicture.bounds.size

    //secondPokemonName.stringValue = secondPokemon.name
    //secondPokemonLevel.stringValue = "Level: \(Int(secondPokemon.level))"
    //secondPokemonHP.stringValue = "\(Int(secondPokemon.HP))/\(Int(secondPokemonOriginalHP))hp"
    secondPokemonHealthBar.doubleValue = Double(secondPokemon.HP/secondPokemonOriginalHP)
    //secondPokemonPicture.image = NSImage(named: "\(secondPokemon.name)")
    //secondPokemonPicture.image.size = secondPokemonPicture.bounds.size

    //TextBoxInfos.stringValue = str

    if firstPokemon.HP <= 0 || secondPokemon.HP <= 0
    {
        button1.enabled = false
        button2.enabled = false
        battleEnded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use a progress bar or a level indicator ? On OSX or iOS ? For NSLevelIndicator you have methods like setIntValue: and for NSProgressIndicator you have setDoubleValue:.

Comment: At least give us a code to show how you calculate health value and what have you tried then community understand exactly what you need.

Comment: The NSLevelIndicator mentioned by @Jean-BaptisteYunès shows a non-striped bar which might be what you need. If you want to use an NSProgressBar you would have to subclass it and override it's drawing method to draw it the way you like.

Comment: I tried the NSLevelIndicator (just replace the NSProgressBar in my code) and the bar is cut in two parts. At initialize only the left part is green for both pokemons, and wont go grey until health points are at 0. (I may not be clear enough...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa and Objective-C resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay NSLevelIndicator worked !
I just had to make sure that each bar's "Style" was on continuous and that the maximum value was 1 and not 2 as it is predefined. Thank you Jean Baptiste

[image: Pic]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/975913ScreenShot20140807at16.png))</sub>